# Is there any way to define a Python function with leading optional arguments?

Tags: python, optional-arguments

As we know, optional arguments must be at the end of the arguments list, like below:

`def func(arg1, arg2, ..., argN=default)`

I saw some exceptions in the `PyTorch` package. For example, we can find this issue in `torch.randint`. As it is shown, it has a leading optional argument in its positional arguments! How could be possible?

```
Docstring:
randint(low=0, high, size, \*, generator=None, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False) -> Tensor
```

How can we define a function in a similar way as above?

Comment: Since you appear to desire an actual working implementation: What calling behaviour do you expect for this? ``\*`` is not a valid signature specifier. Did you mean either of just ``\`` or ``*``?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what exactly `\*` is! I've just copied from the `torch.randint`'s documentation. As you mentioned, I am so curious about its implementation in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single function is not allowed to have only leading optional parameters:

> #### [8.6. Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)
>
> [...] *If a parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the “*” must also have a default value* — this is a syntactic restriction that is not expressed by the grammar.

Note this excludes keyword-only parameters, which never receive arguments by position.

---

If desired, one can emulate such behaviour by manually implementing the argument to parameter matching. For example, one can dispatch based on arity, or explicitly match variadic arguments.

```py
def leading_default(*args):
    # match arguments to "parameters"
    *_, low, high, size = 0, *args
    print(low, high, size)

leading_default(1, 2)     # 0, 1, 2
leading_default(1, 2, 3)  # 1, 2, 3
```

A simple form of dispatch achieves function overloading by iterating signatures and calling the first matching one.

```py
import inspect


class MatchOverload:
    """Overload a function via explicitly matching arguments to parameters on call"""
    def __init__(self, base_case=None):
        self.cases = [base_case] if base_case is not None else []

    def overload(self, call):
        self.cases.append(call)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        failures = []
        for call in self.cases:
            try:
                inspect.signature(call).bind(*args, **kwargs)
            except TypeError as err:
                failures.append(str(err))
            else:
                return call(*args, **kwargs)
        raise TypeError(', '.join(failures))


@MatchOverload
def func(high, size):
    print('two', 0, high, size)


@func.overload
def func(low, high, size):
    print('three', low, high, size)


func(1, 2, size=3)    # three 1 2 3
func(1, 2)            # two 0 1 2
func(1, 2, 3, low=4)  # TypeError: too many positional arguments, multiple values for argument 'low'
```

Comment: @MinsterMiyagi Thanks. But now we can't call this function with keyword arguments. Please take a look at AvivYaniv's response. As he mentioned some parts of its implementation it seems it has several definitions. But as far as I know, it is impossible in python.

Comment: @javadr As mentioned, one can do arity dispatch. *Technically* this is the same mechanism as [singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) – registering several functions and calling the matching one. However, this requires to be tailored to exactly the dispatch behaviour desired – which the question does not detail. Note that as per the signature in the question, none of ``low``, ``high``, or ``size`` seem to allow calling as keyword arguments. They are positional-only, due to preceding ``\``.

Comment: @javadr I've added an example of dispatch/overloading based on signature. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @MinsterMiyagi Although your solution is a very nice implementation, I prefer the way that PEP-484 does. +1

Comment: @javadr Please clarify. PEP 484 is on type *hints* and *annotations* – ``typing.overload`` has no runtime behaviour whatsoever It does not actually overload anything, merely hint an alternate signature to static type checkers.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading

Comment: @javadr I'm well aware of what it is, and especially that *it does not actually overload anything*. As the linked PEP says: "The ``@overload``-decorated definitions are for the benefit of the type checker only, since they will be overwritten by the non-``@overload``-decorated definition, while the latter is used at runtime but should be ignored by a type checker. "

Answer (score 4):

My other answer was about reverse-engineering the torch library, however I want to dedicate this answer on how a similar mechanism can be achieved in a non-hacky, straight forward way.

We have the [multipledispatch](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipledispatch/) library:

> A relatively sane approach to multiple dispatch in Python.
> This implementation of multiple dispatch is efficient, mostly complete, performs static analysis to avoid conflicts, and provides optional namespace support. It looks good too.

So let's utilize it:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(int, int)
def randint(low, high):
    my_randint(low, high)

@dispatch(int)
def randint(high):
    my_randint(0, high)

def my_randint(low, high):
    print(low, high)

# 0 5
randint(5)

# 2 3
randint(2, 3)
```

Comment: @javadr Based on the previous research result, here is an elegant solution on how to achieve "leading optional argument"-like behavior.

Comment: Great and so simple to use. :D

Answer (score 3):

Your discovery fascinated me, as it's indeed illegal in Python (and all other languages I know) to have leading optional arguments, that would surely raise in our case:

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

I got suspicious, yet I've searched on the source code:

I found, at lines 566-596 of [`TensorFactories.cpp`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c88ac2567935c37780e21c65ab4c43ea9f817373/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorFactories.cpp) that there are actually several (!) implementations of `randint`:

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ randint ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Tensor randint(int64_t high, IntArrayRef size, const TensorOptions& options) {
  return native::randint(high, size, c10::nullopt, options);
}

Tensor randint(
    int64_t high,
    IntArrayRef size,
    c10::optional<Generator> generator,
    const TensorOptions& options) {
  return native::randint(0, high, size, generator, options);
}

Tensor randint(
    int64_t low,
    int64_t high,
    IntArrayRef size,
    const TensorOptions& options) {
  return native::randint(low, high, size, c10::nullopt, options);
}

Tensor randint(
    int64_t low,
    int64_t high,
    IntArrayRef size,
    c10::optional<Generator> generator,
    const TensorOptions& options) {
  auto result = at::empty(size, options);
  return result.random_(low, high, generator);
}
```

This pattern reoccurred at lines 466-471 of [`gen_pyi.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7816d53798efcd1dc68a83a2964ee6d4ef4181ca/tools/pyi/gen_pyi.py) where it generates type signatures for top-level functions:

```
        'randint': ['def randint(low: _int, high: _int, size: _size, *,'
                    ' generator: Optional[Generator]=None, {}) -> Tensor: ...'
                    .format(FACTORY_PARAMS),
                    'def randint(high: _int, size: _size, *,'
                    ' generator: Optional[Generator]=None, {}) -> Tensor: ...'
                    .format(FACTORY_PARAMS)],
```

So, what basically happens is that there is no "real" optional parameter rather than several functions, in which one is present and in the other, it's not.

That means, when `randint` is called without the `low` parameter it is set as `0`:

```
Tensor randint(
    int64_t high,
    IntArrayRef size,
    c10::optional<Generator> generator,
    const TensorOptions& options) {
  return native::randint(0, high, size, generator, options);
}
```

Further research, as for OP request on how that possible that there are multiple functions with the same name and different arguments:

Returning once again to [`gen_pyi.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7816d53798efcd1dc68a83a2964ee6d4ef4181ca/tools/pyi/gen_pyi.py) we see that these functions are collected to `unsorted_function_hints` defined at line 436, then it's used to create `function_hints` at lines 509-513, and finally `function_hints` is set to `env` at line 670.

The `env` dictionary is used to write [`pyi`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) stub files.

These stub files make use of Function/method overloading as described in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading).

Function/method overloading, make use of `@overload` decorator:

> The @overload decorator allows describing functions and methods that support multiple different combinations of argument types. This pattern is used frequently in builtin modules and types.

Here is an example:

```
from typing import overload

class bytes:
    ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> bytes: ...
```

So we basically have a definition of the same function `__getitem__` with different arguments.

And another example:

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Iterator, Tuple, TypeVar, overload

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
S = TypeVar('S')

@overload
def map(func: Callable[[T1], S], iter1: Iterable[T1]) -> Iterator[S]: ...
@overload
def map(func: Callable[[T1, T2], S],
        iter1: Iterable[T1], iter2: Iterable[T2]) -> Iterator[S]: ...
# ... and we could add more items to support more than two iterables
```

Here we have a definition of the same function `map` with a different number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen these definitions but I didn't get how to implement it in python! As you know, It is not allowed to have a unique name for several functions with different types of arguments in Python as it is possible in C/C++.

Comment: @javadr Thank you for your respone, elaborated regarding the function/method overloading of PEP-484 :)

Comment: PEP-484 was what I wanted to find out! :D +1

Comment: Please note that  ``typing.overload`` is a no-op at runtime. It merely exists as an *annotation* for use by static type checkers.